# How to convert Torch's pt file to h5 file?

Tags: keras, pytorch, h5py

I want to use Transfer Learning for my model which is built in Keras and requires h5 file in `load_weights()` function.

However, weights I want to use has .pt extension.

How I can convert pt file to h5?